# When I try to break blocks in Minecraft, they reappear

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For some reason, I can't break any blocks in Minecraft.  They break, but then they reappear and don't drop anything.  Iv'e tried restarting and updating, but nothing seems to work.  What do I try next?

Comment: @FAE Not completely, no. If the blocks do appear to break, then re-appear, that's a different issue than the blocks not breaking at all.

Comment: @BillyMailman: No, it is a dupe, just like the other 2 dozen questions we've closed as dupe.

Comment: The question that this is supposedly duplicate of is not the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If blocks are showing the breaking animation, but reappear shortly after you finish, this is usually just a sign of bad lag in Multiplayer. Your client believes you are done breaking the block, so tells the server you have stopped. Due to lag, the server disagrees, and tells your client that the block is still there, at which point it re-appears.